# How to run GitHub code in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

I try to run this code in my own computer: https://github.com/yicheng-w/CommonSenseMultiHopQA

I've downloaded the zip file but I have no idea how can I run this code in Jupyter notebook. It's my first time that I want to run a code from Github. I couldn't find any complete guide for that.

I have Python 3.6 on Windows.

Comment: You can only use .ipynb file in jupyter notebook. try following the instructions given and running the code in a terminal/cmd

Comment: How can I find those instructions? could you please give me a link to those instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use the `.ipynb` file in jupyter notebook. Try following the instructions given and running the code in a terminal/cmd.

By instructions I mean what is written in the [README.md](https://github.com/yicheng-w/CommonSenseMultiHopQA/blob/master/README.md) file of that GitHub repo. See, the files in this repo are `.py` files and not `.ipynb` files. The correct way to run them is to run them on a command prompt if you are in a windows machine or in a terminal if you are on Linux/Mac.

- Step 0:

  `Clone the repo`

  Clone the repo that you have linked, namely `CommonSenseMultiHopQA`. For cloning the repo you must have git installed on your system. If you don't have it get it from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads). When working on Github it is necessary to know how to use git. If you don't then follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTuRUfjRe54Eea17-YfnOOAx).
- Step 1:

  > First, to setup the directory structure, please run setup.sh to create the appropriate directories.

  `.sh` files are bash files that contain bash scripts. Run these using the command `./setup.sh`. Here is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AiqegwnskE) on running them. Running this command will automatically create the necessary directory (folder structure).
- Step 2:

  ```
  cd raw_data
  git clone https://github.com/deepmind/narrativeqa.git
  ```

  The first command changes your directory to `raw_data`. These a Linux commands (`cd` is available in windows too) you can learn about them [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS1QulWo1RIb9WVQGJ_vh-RQusbZgO_As). The second command clones the `narrativeqa` into the `raw_data` folder.
- Step 3:

  For this step, you must know how to run `.py` files from the cmd/terminal. [Watch this video for that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1Q8xs2YC8Q)

  > We need to build processed datasets with extracted commonsense
  > information. For NarrativeQA, we run:
  >
  > ```
  > python src/config.py \
  >     --mode build_dataset \
  >     --data_dir raw_data/narrativeqa \
  >     --load_commonsense \
  >     --commonsense_file data/cn_relations_orig.txt \
  >     --processed_dataset_train data/narrative_qa_train.jsonl \
  >     --processed_dataset_valid data/narrative_qa_valid.jsonl \
  >     --processed_dataset_test data/narrative_qa_test.jsonl
  > ```
  >
  > To build processed datasets with extracted commonsense for WikiHop, we
  > run:
  >
  > ```
  > python src/config.py \
  >     --mode build_wikihop_dataset \
  >     --data_dir raw_data/qangaroo_v1.1 \
  >     --load_commonsense \
  >     --commonsense_file data/cn_relations_orig.txt \
  >     --processed_dataset_train data/wikihop_train.jsonl \
  >     --processed_dataset_valid data/wikihop_valid.jsonl
  > ```

  Both the long commands are running `config.py` file inside the `src` folder. The `--something` are aurguments passed to the `python <filename>` command. The first one :

  > ```
  > python src/config.py \
  >     --mode build_dataset \
  >     --data_dir raw_data/narrativeqa \
  >     --load_commonsense \
  >     --commonsense_file data/cn_relations_orig.txt \
  >     --processed_dataset_train data/narrative_qa_train.jsonl \
  >     --processed_dataset_valid data/narrative_qa_valid.jsonl \
  >     --processed_dataset_test data/narrative_qa_test.jsonl
  > ```

  extracts commonsense for narrativeqa and the second:

  > ```
  > python src/config.py \
  >     --mode build_wikihop_dataset \
  >     --data_dir raw_data/qangaroo_v1.1 \
  >     --load_commonsense \
  >     --commonsense_file data/cn_relations_orig.txt \
  >     --processed_dataset_train data/wikihop_train.jsonl \
  >     --processed_dataset_valid data/wikihop_valid.jsonl
  > ```

  extracts commonsense for WikiHop...
- Finally, The following commands are for Training & Evaluation:

  > Training
  >
  > To train models for NarrativeQA, run:
  >
  > ```
  > python src/config.py \
  >     --version {commonsense_nqa, baseline_nqa} \
  >     --model_name <model_name> \
  >     --processed_dataset_train data/narrative_qa_train.jsonl \
  >     --processed_dataset_valid data/narrative_qa_valid.jsonl \
  >     --batch_size 24 \
  >     --max_target_iterations 15 \
  >     --dropout_rate 0.2
  > ```
  >
  > To train models for WikiHop, run:
  >
  > ```
  > python src/config.py \
  >     --version {commonsense_wh, baseline_wh} \
  >     --model_name <model_name> \
  >     --elmo_options_file lm_data/wh/elmo_2x4096_512_2048cnn_2xhighway_options.json \
  >     --elmo_weight_file lm_data/wh/elmo_2x4096_512_2048cnn_2xhighway_weights.hdf5 \
  >     --elmo_token_embedding_file lm_data/wh/elmo_token_embeddings.hdf5 \
  >     --elmo_vocab_file lm_data/wh/wikihop_vocab.txt \
  >     --processed_dataset_train data/wikihop_train.jsonl \
  >     --processed_dataset_valid data/wikihop_valid.jsonl \
  >     --multiple_choice \
  >     --max_target_iterations 4 \
  >     --max_iterations 8 \
  >     --batch_size 16 \
  >     --max_target_iterations 4 \
  >     --max_iterations 8 \
  >     --max_context_iterations 1300 \
  >     --dropout_rate 0.2
  > ```
  >
  > Evaluation
  >
  > To evaluate NarrativeQA, we need to first generate official answers on
  > the test set. To do so, run:
  >
  > ```
  > python src/config.py \
  >     --mode generate_answers \
  >     --processed_dataset_valid data/narrative_qa_valid.jsonl \
  >     --processed_dataset_test data/narrative_qa_test.jsonl
  > ```

---

Alternatively, if you really want to run these commands in `jupyter notebook` then all you need to do is to add a `!` before all them and run them different cells.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to be a complete and straightforward guide that I couldn't find on the internet. Thank you for sharing

Answer (score 4):

When you use ('!') in any cell of your Jupyter  notebook it acts as a command slimier as Terminal
Here a sample example Example How to clone git file in Jupyter Notebook.

```
! git clone https://github.com/yicheng-w/CommonSenseMultiHopQA.git
```

After write Upper Command in Cell you need to run cell to execute command and you Git Repo is successfully clone to your notebook.

Comment: could you please explain what happens with that command?it is like downloading them? or running them?sorry if my question is rudimentary

Comment: Hello @A,mh, `git clone` clones the repo on to your computer. It is equivalent to downloading it. This doesn't run the code.

Comment: you can run all the terminal command in Jupyter notebook upper one is just an example to run terminal command in Juyper notebook.